# Apply Subversion auto-props after the fact

Tags: svn

For some reason the auto-props in `~/subversion/config` were not applied; specifically `Makefile* = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Id HeadURL`. Is there some quick way to apply all current auto-props recursively?

```
$ grep enable-auto-props ~/.subversion/config | grep -v ^#
enable-auto-props = yes
```

Comment: Did you enable auto-props by setting enable-auto-props = yes?

Comment: Yep, changed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subversion's automatic properties affect only adds and imports (read [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto)). If they are not applied to newly added files, check whether *enable-auto-props* option is set to *yes*.